# NullPointerException thrown from alertdialog when starting new activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-sdk-2.3

I am developing a Exception Handler for an android phone application. I am trying to link the positive Submit Report button on the error box to direct the user to ContactActivity... the contact support page. When the user presses the Submit Button a NullPointerException is thrown from the context of the intent I believe. I have tried ExceptionHandler.this, getApplicationcontext(), getBaseContext(), and nothing seems to work and I don't want to go through the trouble of setting up a custom profile because I am kind of in a rush but I have been stumped on this problem for hours.

```
public class ExceptionHandler extends BaseActivity {

private String phoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
private String phoneDevice = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
private String phoneVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
private String errorTag;
private Context context;

public ExceptionHandler (Context context, String tag){
    this.context = context;
    errorTag = tag;
}

public void alert(Exception e){

    AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    messageBox.setTitle("Oops...");
    messageBox.setMessage("An error has occurred .\n\n" +
            "Error: " + e.toString() + "\n" +
            "Location: " + AtlasApplication.MenuTitle + "\n" +
            "Phone Model: " + phoneModel + "\n" +
            "Phone Device: " + phoneDevice + "\n" +
            "API Version: " + phoneVersion + "\n");
   messageBox.setPositiveButton("Send Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            try {
                startActivityWithAnim(new Intent(context, ContactActivity.class));
                //I have also tried (ContactActivity.getIntent(context))
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    });
    messageBox.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    messageBox.create();
    messageBox.show();
}

public void reportError(Exception e){

}

}
```

Comment: Post error log and which line you'r getting error?

Comment: How do I access them?

Comment: you are defining a custom constructor for an activity. it suggests that you may be trying to instanciate activities yourself, which will definitely crahs.

Comment: I'm getting the error from the following line:

startActivityWithAnim(new Intent(context, ContactActivity.class));
                //I have also tried (ContactActivity.getIntent(context))

Comment: Start your activity with `context` like `context.startActivityWithAnim(new Intent(context, ContactActivity.class));`

Comment: don't catch your exception or do a `Log.e("exception", "exception", e);` and check the logcat and print the complet log here

Comment: @MichaelCollins can you post the part of code where you have initialized "context

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, if you want ExceptionHandler just to show alert, you don't need to extend BaseActivity (your customized Activity). For example, if you want to call ExceptionHandler from MainActivity, you can do like this

```
ExceptionHandler exHandler = new ExceptionHandler(getApplicationContext(),"MAIN_ACTIVITY"); 
exHandler.alert(new Exception()); //Put your exception in the parameter.
```

If you are creating new Activity for ExceptionHandler, you don't need to pass context in arguments. For the NullPointerException, try

```
context.startActivityWithAnim(new Intent(context,ContactActivity.class));
```

Hope this helps :)